# Filter DataFrame to Duplicated Items and Compute Groupwise Means on Result

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Ok, so here is what I'm trying to do:

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(
{'a' : [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3],
 'b' : [23,45,62,24,45,34,25,62],
 })
```

I managed to calculate the mean of column 'a' grouped by the column 'b' by using the following code:

```
data.groupby('b', as_index=False)['a'].mean()
```

which resulted in a DataFrame like this:

[image: current DataFrame]

However, I'd like to only calculate the mean for the values of 'b' that occur more than once in the DataFrame, resulting in a Dataframe like this:

[image: Desired DataFrame]

I tried to do it by using the following line:

```
data.groupby('b', as_index=False).filter(lambda group: len(group)>1)['a'].mean()
```

but it results in the mean of the lines 1, 2, 4 and 7, which is obviously not what I want.
Can someone please help me to obtain the desired DataFrame and tell me what I'm getting wrong on the use of the filter function?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Grouping on Duplicates

You can do this with `data['b'].duplicated(keep=False)` to create a boolean mask first:

```
>>> data[data['b'].duplicated(keep=False)].groupby('b', as_index=False)['a'].mean()                                                                         
    b    a
0  45  1.5
1  62  2.0
```

`data.b.duplicated(keep=False)` marks all duplicated occurrences as True and lets you restrict output to those rows:

```
>>> data.b.duplicated(keep=False)                                                                                                                        
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
5    False
6    False
7     True
Name: b, dtype: bool

>>> data[data.b.duplicated(keep=False)]                                                                                                                  
   a   b
1  1  45
2  1  62
4  2  45
7  3  62
```

#### Update: Grouping by Arbitrary Number of Occurrences

> Can this solution be generalized to look for an arbitrary number of occurrences? Let's say I wanted to calculate the mean only for values that occurred more than 5 times on the DataFrame.

In this scenario, you need to generate a boolean mask of the same shape as in the example above, but using a slightly different approach.

Here is one way:

```
>>> vc = data['b'].map(data['b'].value_counts(sort=False))
>>> vc                                                                                                                                                   

0    1
1    2
2    2
3    1
4    2
5    1
6    1
7    2
Name: b, dtype: int64
```

These are the element-wise counts for each element of `b`.  To get this to a mask (say you want means for only count == 2, which is the same as the above in this example, but could be extended for any int):

```
mask = vc == 2  # or > 5, in your case
data[mask].groupby('b', as_index=False)['a'].mean()
```

Comment: This is a very nice way to do it!

Answer (score 1):

You were pretty close:

```
data.groupby('b').filter(lambda g:len(g)>1).groupby('b',as_index=False).mean()
```

results in the answer you were looking for:

```
    b    a
0  45  1.5
1  62  2.0
```

Comment: Would you care to explain why using groupby twice does the trick?

Comment: The first group by combined with filter produces records where "b" appears more than once. On a reduced subset, we can then do group by on "b" to produce mean of "a" for each "b" group.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter before your dataframe via `loc` before `groupby`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3],
                   'b' : [23,45,62,24,45,34,25,62]})

counts = df['b'].value_counts()

res = df.loc[df['b'].isin(counts[counts > 1].index)]\
        .groupby('b', as_index=False)['a'].mean()

print(res)

    b    a
0  45  1.5
1  62  2.0
```